# Index blocks of rows based on begin and end value

Tags: r

I want to create an index column that looks at certain keywords like "start" and "end" to assign unique IDs and has a counter/loop to assign the next number in the sequence when it maps the next "start"

```
library(data.table)
in.data <- data.table(colA=c("random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "start", "random", "random", "end", "start", "random", "end", "start", "end", "random"))
in.data$wanted.column <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, NA)

           in.data
              colA wanted.column
         1: random            NA
         2: random            NA
         3: random            NA
         4: random            NA
         5: random            NA
         6:  start             1
         7: random             1
         8: random             1
         9:    end             1
        10:  start             2
        11: random             2
        12:    end             2
        13:  start             3
        14:    end             3
        15: random            NA
```

Comment: What is the expected result in case of two subsequent "start" values without an "end" inbetween? (Likewise two subsequent "end" values without an "start" in between?

Comment: @rq6754, please open a completely new question with a general example, that covers all border cases. There you could also address Uwe 's comment.

Comment: New question has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935729/index-blocks-of-rows-based-on-begin-and-end-value-all-possible-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data:

```
in.data <- data.table(colA=c("random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "start", "random", "random", "end", "start", "random", "end", "start", "end", "random"))
in.data$wanted.column <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, NA)
```

code:

```
in.data$wanted.column2 = NA
IND <- min(which(in.data$colA %in% "start")):max(which(in.data$colA %in% "end"))
in.data$wanted.column2[IND] = cumsum(in.data$colA %in% "start")[IND]
```

result:

```
#      colA wanted.column wanted.column2
# 1: random            NA             NA
# 2: random            NA             NA
# 3: random            NA             NA
# 4: random            NA             NA
# 5: random            NA             NA
# 6:  start             1              1
# 7: random             1              1
# 8: random             1              1
# 9:    end             1              1
#10:  start             2              2
#11: random             2              2
#12:    end             2              2
#13:  start             3              3
#14:    end             3              3
#15: random            NA             NA
```

---

- prepopulate a column with NA
- get indices from first "start" to last "end"
- make groups and add them where intended

Comment: Thanks @Andre, the extension of the logic does not seem to work where it does impute an NA for the 'random' rows between the 'end' and the 'start'. See my post below for output.

Comment: @rq6754 I replaced `==` with `%in%`. This should solve the issue your having. Please let me know.

Comment: it still gives me the previous iteration of the sequence and it does not impute an NA.